# .include? array[rand(array.length)]

Tags: arrays, ruby, random, include

I'm trying to write an alternative to shuffle method and can't understand why it returns duplicates. Does anyone see the problem? Thanks so much!

```
def return_random_songs(songs)
  returned_songs = []
  while returned_songs.length < songs.length
    unless returned_songs.include?(songs[rand(songs.length)])
      returned_songs << songs[rand(songs.length)]
    end
  end
  return returned_songs
end

songs = ["song 1", "song 2", "song 3", "song 4"]
pp return_random_songs(songs)
=> ["song 2", "song 4", "song 1", "song 1"] #duplicates!
```

Comment: Why are you trying to write an alternative to `shuffle`? Use the existing method as its well tested and already available. .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you compute twice the random song: for the check and when you add the song (so you don't know what ends up in the `returned_songs` array). Try

```
def return_random_songs(songs)
  returned_songs = []
  while returned_songs.length < songs.length
    random_song = songs[rand(songs.length)]
    unless returned_songs.include?(random_song)
      returned_songs << random_song
    end
  end
  return returned_songs
end
```

Comment: Thank you! (awww.. such a simple thing to overlook)

Comment: my pleasure miss